# How to not burn bridges while giving notice

Tags: burning-bridges

I am going to give notice after my parental leave ends.
I am on parental leave and got a good job offer .
I cannot tell my manager immediately because I am stuck in India for visa stamping.
Once back to US I will give the notice.
Will it look very bad on me to give notice after parental leave .
How to avoid burning the bridge in such a case , my manager is a great guy

Comment: There is not much you can do other than to give as much notice as possible, so they can replace you as quickly as possible.

Comment: Wait, are you using the job you're going to quit as an excuse to get a foreign worker visa stamped? Pretty sure that'd be immigration fraud. Do the right thing, and get the people you're *actually* going to be working for to sponsor your visa.

Comment: No , immigration fraud . It is just the process that we have to follow. I think you misunderstood my question . Also you are not aware about stamping nightmare. But I am not surprised

Comment: If your current boss/company has paid for this current trip back to India for visa stamping (and probably also paid filing fees too) they're not going to be very happy with you. They can't legally ask you to repay them (unless you signed a contract with them which has something like a 'liquidated damages' clause if you quit 'early'). But in your situation I think this bridge is jus waiting to catch fire ...

Comment: If you're using your real name as your username, you can ask the mods to change it by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will it look very bad on me to give notice after parental leave

Yes it might look bad. It can look like you're using their company for visa reasons.

That said it's perfectly ok to hand in your notice after your parental leave. There's no reason for any bridge burning, or for anyone to take it personally, it's just a career decision. So long as you hand in the contracted notice you're fine.

Comment: I'd add that while it will annoy some managers, quitting after the end of maternity leave is fairly common so it won't come as a huge shock.  There's always an element of "Will X actually come back" any time someone in the US leaves for a new kid.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight feel free to edit something along those lines in. I'm not familiar with the US, but it seems reasonable.